# Does Darwin Raw Pet Food Have Metal In It?

Tags: dogs, diet

My wife and I are thinking about switching to a new (different) raw pet food diet for our dog.  She is currently eating Primal Formula but we have heard that Darwin is also good.  However, we encountered this article:

http://www.poisonedpets.com/darwins-dog-food/

Does anyone here have any experience with it?  Have you found non-consumable bits in it?

Comment: You really need to look for independent reports. The FDA and your State Department of Agriculture may assist you in this. If the report is true, they may be able to tell you if the issue has been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I spoke with them.  They owned that a couple of years ago they did have an incident but it was resolved quickly and that they have excellent procedures in place to catch problems.  They invited me to tour their facility.  My wife and can count at least a dozen friends who swear by Darwin so we decided to give them a shot.  Besides, we are always very careful when feeding our pup.  We don't just throw food in a bowl and give it to her with out examining it.

I am willing to say that the answer to my question is that, No, Darwin Pet Food does not have unconsumable bits in it.

Comment: I'm impressed they offered to give you a tour!

Comment: Accept, and post some piccies.